# How do I derive this internal energy equation?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy

So my question is probably quite basic, but I have found this paper online.

[http://www.astro.lu.se/~david/teaching/SPH/notes/annurev.aa.30.090192.pdf](http://www.astro.lu.se/%7Edavid/teaching/SPH/notes/annurev.aa.30.090192.pdf)

And it defines the rate of change of thermal energy per unit mass as:

$\dfrac{du}{dt} = -\left( \dfrac{P}{\rho} \right) \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}$

Where $u$ is the internal energy, $P$ pressure, $\rho$ density and $\mathbf{v}$ is the velocity.

**My question is then; where does this equation come from? How does one define that the internal energy is given in this way?**

The paper is about SPH which is a Lagrangian method, but it does not seem to have something to do with this, other than it being the total derivative which is used.

Kind regards

Comment: It looks like this is just the differential version of the first law of thermodynamics, assuming adiabatic reversible expansion or compression.

Comment: @ChetMiller thanks for the hint! Looking at some ressource; https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Meredith_College/Thermodynamics/15%3A_Extension_11_-_Legendre_Transforms/15.01%3A_Differential_Forms_of_Fundamental_Equations I see that they define it as:

$dU =TdS − PdV$

Assuming it is only volume work being performed. I struggle moving forward with this though since I cannot see explicitly where $\mathbf{v}$ would come in and how the fraction $\frac{P}{\rho}$ occurs.

Comment: You are aware that, in this equation, v is the fluid velocity, and, from the continuity equation. the divergence of the velocity is equal to minus the Lagrangian time derivative of the natural log of the density. So the pressure term becomes P times the Lagrangian time derivative of the specific volume.

Answer (score 1):

This is a short summary of the classic Eckart [1] paper that I think is relevant to your question. The equation of continuity is $\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot (\rho \bf{v})$ that can also be written as $\rho \frac{D \gamma}{Dt} = \nabla \cdot \bf{v} $ where $\gamma = 1/\rho$ and $D$ is the material derivative that for any function $f$ and closed volume $\mathcal V$ moving with the fluid  satisfies $\frac {d}{dt}\int_{\mathcal V}\rho f d\tau = \int_{\mathcal V} \rho \frac{Df}{Dt} d\tau$.

In the absence of external volume forces the motion of the fluid satisfies the hydrodynamic equation$$\rho\frac{D\bf{v}}{Dt}=- \nabla p + \nabla \cdot  {\wp}$$ where $p$ and $\wp$ are the hydrostatic pressure and tensor of the viscous stress, resp.
The kinetic energy is defined by $K=\int_{\mathcal V} \frac{1}{2}\rho \mathbf{v}^2d\tau$ and then 
$$\frac{dK}{dt}=\int_{\mathcal V} \rho\mathbf{v}\cdot\frac{D\mathbf{v}}{Dt}d\tau\\=\int_{\mathcal{V}}\mathbf{v}\cdot(-\nabla p+\nabla\cdot\wp)\\=-\oint_{\partial \mathcal V}(p \mathbf v -\wp \cdot \mathbf{v})\cdot d\mathbf{\sigma} + \int_{\mathcal V} p\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v} -(\wp \cdot \nabla \cdot\mathbf{v}) d\tau$$
Now calculate the rate at which the fluid inside the volume $\mathcal V$ bounded by surface $\mathcal{ \partial V}$ does work on the fluid outside the surface.
Assuming the fluid has an internal energy function $u=u(\rho,p)$ we can write the total energy balance as

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathcal V} (\frac{1}{2}\rho \mathbf{v}^2 d\tau + \rho u) d\tau = -\oint_{\mathcal \partial V} \mathbf{q} \cdot d\sigma - \oint_{\partial \mathcal V}(p \mathbf v -\wp \cdot \mathbf{v})\cdot d\mathbf{\sigma} $$

Thus we get
$$\int_{\mathcal V} \left( \rho \frac{Du}{Dt} + (p \nabla \cdot \mathbf v -(\wp \cdot \nabla )\cdot \mathbf{v}) + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q}\right) d\tau =0 $$This being true for all closed surface we finally get the 1st law of thermodynamics for fluids as
$$\rho \frac{Du}{Dt} + (p \nabla \cdot \mathbf v -(\wp \cdot \nabla )\cdot \mathbf{v}) + \nabla \cdot \mathbf{q}=0$$

Now Eckart applies a very clever trick, noting that we have assumed $u=u(\gamma, p)$ (here I change from density $\rho$ to specific volume $\gamma = 1/\rho$) we can write
$$\rho \frac{Du}{Dt} +p \nabla \cdot \mathbf v  = \rho \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \gamma} + p\right) \frac{D \gamma}{Dt} + \rho\frac{\partial u }{\partial p}\frac{Dp}{Dt}$$

Next, note that a two-variable differential form is always integrable, that is there are two functions $\theta$ and $\eta$ such that
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial \gamma} + p= \theta \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial \gamma}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial p} = \theta \frac{\partial \eta}{\partial p}$$

from which we get the "2nd law" in the form of
$$\rho \theta \frac{D\eta}{Dt} +\nabla \cdot \mathbf q = (\wp \cdot \nabla)\cdot \mathbf v $$ or $$\rho \frac{D \eta}{Dt} +\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\mathbf q}{\theta} \right)= - \frac {1}{\theta^2}\mathbf {q} \cdot \nabla \theta +\frac{1}{\theta}(\wp \cdot \nabla)\cdot \mathbf v  $$  where $\eta$ is the entropy per unit mass and $\theta$ is the temperature.
Eckart goes on to show that for a normal viscous fluid $(\wp \cdot \nabla)\cdot \mathbf v \ge 0$ and heat conduction $\mathbf{q} = \kappa \nabla \theta$, $\kappa >0$  from which follows Clausius's inequality in local differential form:
$$\rho \frac{D \eta}{Dt} +\nabla \cdot \left(\frac{\mathbf q}{\theta} \right)\ge0$$
or in integral form:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\mathcal V} \rho \eta d\tau  +\oint_{\partial\mathcal V} \left(\frac{\mathbf q}{\theta} \right)\cdot d\sigma \ge 0$$

[1] Eckart: Thermodynamics of irreversible processes I Simple Fluid, PHYSICAL REVIEW, 1940 VOLUM E 58, pp267-269

Comment: Thanks for your comment!

http://www.ita.uni-heidelberg.de/~dullemond/lectures/num_fluid_2012/Chapter_1_improved.pdf 

Equation 1.60 is where they derive it here, which shows another way than what you go through. I struggle with both of them still, but nice to see your way

Comment: I did not down vote. I have less than 15 reputation right now, if I like / dislike it will not show up anyways