# What does thermodynamically consistent mean?

Tags: thermodynamics, navier-stokes

I am currently dealing with Cahn-Hilliard-Navier-Stokes equations. Many paper regarding these kind equations talk about the "thermodynamical consistency" of the presented models. For example, in

- S.Aland, A.Voigt, [Benchmark computations of diffuse interface models for two-dimensional bubble dynamics](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/fld.2611), 2011,

the authors present three models and quickly state whether these models are thermodynamically consistent.

Unfortunately, I could not find a decent definition/explanation on what thermodynamically consistent acutally means. Can someone help me out?

Comment: It is abused semantics, just to inform the reader that the hydrodynamic model is (claimed to be) consistent with the thermodynamics of the system: when there is no flow and no gradients, hydrodynamics should automatically reduce to thermodynamics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the concept originates in the works of Bridgman and Eckart, see for [example](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.58.267),  and a short review of that [work](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/588441/how-do-i-derive-this-internal-energy-equation/588489#588489), where Eckart  proves, with an unusual clarity for works in irreversible thermodynamics, that for a simple fluid:

> The rate of increase of the entropy of a simple viscous fluid, capable of conducting heat, is investigated in greater detail than has hitherto been customary. It is shown that, if Kelvin's hypothesis concerning the absolute temperature be adopted, and the usual law of viscosity be assumed, the requirements of the second law are satisfied.

In other words, he shows that the constitutive relationships of a simple fluid while being compressible, viscous and heat conducting, allows for a positive entropy generation function, and thus both the 1st and the 2nd laws hold everywhere, both locally and globally, all the time.

In this context, Eckart *proves* that the entropy function satisfies the so-called Clausius-Duhem inequality: $$\tfrac{d}{dt}\int m\eta d\tau+ \oint \tfrac{1}{\theta}\mathbf q \cdot d\mathbf{\sigma}\ge 0,$$ where $m,\eta, \theta, \mathbf q,d\tau, d\mathbf{\sigma}$ are: mass density, specific entropy, temperature, heat flux, volume element , surface element. This is the required thermodynamic consistency.

Comment: +1 to both this and your previous answer, that series of papers by Eckart is indeed a classic!

Comment: @Quillo thanks, I learned of  Eckart's work from Truesdell who wrote "However that may be, no such estimate can be just if it fails to cast in relief the greater deserts of another early author, C. ECKART (1940), who obtained and used a major case of the Clausius-Duhem inequality, who treated heat conduction and viscosity explicitly on the basis of it, who attempted to split inequalities into parts without appeal to any nonexistent theorem,...

Comment: ...who derived some correct consequences of the irreversibility principle at an equilibrium state-and who did not obfuscate the scene by any circular or inapplicable rule of symmetry."  I think this was the first time that I told myself now I am about to *start* to understand what thermodynamics is about... I still do not but at least that was *a* start.

Comment: Sommerfeld: "Thermodynamics is a funny subject. The first time you go through it, you don’t understand it at all. The second time you go through it, you think you understand it, except for one or two points. The third time you go through it, you know you don’t understand it, but by that time you are so used to the subject, it doesn’t bother you anymore."